# why returning to other view from action is bad?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I m working in MVC and some one recently has reviewed my code. On some places in my controller actions I was returning to other views, for example in below code in `Index` action I m returning to `List` view:

```
public virtual ActionResult Index(Student student)
{
    // Logic
    return View("List", student);
}
```

Why it is not a good practice ? I did not get any idea why this is wrong. Kindly guide me so I can correct this.

Comment: Why don't you ask the person who was reviewing your code?

Comment: @JonSkeet I can't as it was from client and I dont have access to them.

Comment: Then you're basically asking us to read someone else's mind. We don't even know the exact comment that they raised.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with returning a different view to the default action view. The only thing I can think that might be unsettling to some is it does not following the MVC paradigm of convention over configuration.

This may make it difficult to follow someones code if they have lots of actions with names that are different to their corresponding view names i.e:

```
public ActionResult Index(int id)
{
    //logic
    return View("StupidName");
}
```

Convention would have you think the index action would return the Index view, although it doesn't and now the programmer has to go look for the StupidName view. This may seem harmless for one action but if someone has written multiple actions that return differently named views it can be difficult to follow the flow of the project.

Alternatively you could ask the code reviewer why he thinks it is a bad practice. Communication is key in a team.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I see nothing wrong with this as long **as the logic for compiling the input for the view isn't duplicated**.

If you have to copy a lot of code to ensure that the model for the view is correct, and this isn't really the responsibility of your action, you'd rather redirect to the action instead of calling the view directly.

If this is not the case, or there is a very specific situation, I don't see why this is a problem.

Consider these examples:

1. You have a error dialog view. If the model just consists of a single property defining the message, it is no problem to call the view directly;
2. If you have the same dialog, but in order to create the model you have to fetch some general information from the database, have some custom logic, etc., then it is probably best to call the (or create an) action doing this all for you. Also, the number of calls to that view may matter in your decision.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
public virtual ActionResult Index(Student student)
{
    // Logic
    return RedirectToAction("List");
}
```